# Dont want to show Tab Layout on perticular tab click

Tags: android, android-intent, android-tabhost

I have used a TabHost in my application with three tabs suppose A, B and C...

In general when we click on any tab it will open new activity "with TAB LAYOUT", but i want to do something different When I do click on tab c an Intent should be shown and I don't want tab layout for that Intent

How can I do it?

Thanking you all!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by setting tab change listener:

```
getTabHost().setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        if (tabId.equalsIgnoreCase(cTabId))
            startActivity(intentForCActivity);
    }
});
```

---

But you should understand that this is bad idea - user will wonder what happens. It's not the best practice to wonder user with creating nonobvious interface decisions.

Comment: No I am using that tab to bring him on to the main menu. And thanks a lot for your valuable reply!!!!!!